# Specifying port 80 in URL gives different result than no port specified

Tags: node.js, web, heroku, server

I created and deployed app on Heroku. Now accessing the app via this URL: https://electricity-manager1.herokuapp.com/api/hello works as expected the result is:

> {"express":"Hello From Express"}

But when I specify port in the URL like this:

https://electricity-manager1.herokuapp.com/api/hello:80

I get different result: the home page.

How is it different? I tried with port 443 but same result.
I thought port 80 and 443 are the default ports when using HTTP and HTTPS protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the port in the wrong place. It should [immediately follow the host, as part of the authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax):

> Every HTTP URL conforms to the syntax of a generic URI. The *URI generic syntax* consists of a hierarchical sequence of five *components*:
>
> ```
> URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
> ```
>
> where the authority component divides into three subcomponents:
>
> ```
> authority = [userinfo@]host[:port]
> ```

Here are updated links for you:

- http://electricity-manager1.herokuapp.com:80/api/hello
- https://electricity-manager1.herokuapp.com:443/api/hello